# Objective-C: Unable to send/receive data after two matchmaking two devices using Game Center

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center

I was hoping someone would be able to help with an Objective-C problem I have relating to sending and receiving information between two devices using GameCenter once they have been through matchmaking.

I am using a textbook called Beginning iOS Game Center and Game Kit as my guide, and it is going through an example program, but I am stuck on the part where I would like to receive data from a device playing the game.

I can successfully matchmake two devices and the appropriate view to appear. I have two functions in my GameCenterManager.m file to send information - one being the following:

```
- (void)sendStringToAllPeers:(NSString *)dataString reliable:(BOOL)reliable
{
NSLog(@"Send String To All Peers");
NSLog(@"Data String: %@", dataString);
NSLog(@"match or session %@", self.matchOrSession);

if (self.matchOrSession == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"GC Manager matchorsession ivar was not set - this needs to be set with the GKMatch or GKSession before sending or receiving data");
    return;
}
NSData *dataToSend = [dataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
GKSendDataMode mode;
if (reliable)
{
    mode = GKSendDataReliable;
}
else{
    mode = GKSendDataUnreliable;
}

NSError *error = nil;
if ([self.matchOrSession isKindOfClass:[GKSession class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Match or session 1");
    NSLog(@"Data to send: %@", dataToSend);
    [self.matchOrSession sendDataToAllPeers:dataToSend withDataMode:mode error:&error];

}

else if ([self.matchOrSession isKindOfClass:[GKMatch class]])
{
    NSLog(@"Match or session 2");
    NSLog(@"Data to send: %@", dataToSend);
    [self.matchOrSession sendDataToAllPlayers:dataToSend withDataMode:mode error:&error];
}

else
{   
    NSLog(@"GC Manager matchOrSession was not a GKMatch or a GK Session, we are unable to send data");
}

if (error != nil)
{
NSLog(@"An error occurred while sending data %@", [error localizedDescription]);

}
}
```

this function I call from a function in my racetohundredViewController.m file:

```
- (void)generateAndSendHostNumber;
{
NSLog(@"Generate and send host number");
randomHostNumber = arc4random();
NSString *randomNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"$Host:%f", randomHostNumber];
NSLog(@"the random number string is: %@", randomNumberString);
[self.gcManager sendStringToAllPeers:randomNumberString reliable: YES];
}
```

I successfully get the following NSLog output resulting from this:

```
2013-01-02 22:27:43.519 First to 50[1376:907] Send String To All Peers
2013-01-02 22:27:43.520 First to 50[1376:907] Data String: $Host:2087825492.000000
2013-01-02 22:27:43.521 First to 50[1376:907] match or session <GKMatch 0x200853d0 expected count: 0 seqnum: 2
G:1656671636:connected
reinvitedPlayers:(
)>
2013-01-02 22:27:43.522 First to 50[1376:907] Match or session 2
2013-01-02 22:27:43.523 First to 50[1376:907] Data to send: <24486f73 743a3230 38373832 35343932 2e303030 303030>
```

So I can see the 'Data to send' output which is great.

However I now have the command

```
[self.matchOrSession sendDataToAllPeers:dataToSend withDataMode:mode error:&error];
```

which doesn't seem to take me anywhere at all. I have the following function in GameCenterManager.m:

```
- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context
{
NSLog(@"*****Receive Data In Session");
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dataString, peer, session,  nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"data", @"peer", @"session", nil]];

[self callDelegateOnMainThread: @selector(receivedData:) withArg: dataDictionary error: nil];
}
```

But I am not seeing the NSLog output from this. Likewise, I have a function in my racetohundredViewController.m file

```
- (void)receivedData:(NSDictionary *)dataDictionary
{
    NSLog(@"------Received Data");
}
```

which also doesn't get called; presumably because the previous function isn't able to call it.

I have been trying to work out why this doesn't work for a while now without any avail. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong? I hope I have put in all the relevant code but if you have any questions please ask.

Thanks to all, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I realised what I had done after looking online at other people's problems with the same thing. I had not set my delegate after finding a match, a very rookie mistake!